# Web Scraping Location Data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage for address data (the highlighted street address shown in this image:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DixNu.png)) using the find() function of the BeautifulSoup library. Most online tutorials only provide examples where data can be easily pinpointed to a certain class; however, for this particular site, the street address is a  element within a larger class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" and I'm not sure how to get at it with the find() function.

What would be the arguments to find() to get the street address in this example? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DixNu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, it will find the div element with the class "dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" then search for td elements within it and print the first td elements text:

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"class":"dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite"})
for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all("td")
    print (tdTags[0].text)
```

the above example assumes you want to print the first td element from all the div elements with the class "dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" otherwise

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"class":"dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite"})
tdTags = divTag[0].find_all("td")
print (tdTags[0].text)
```